# Connecting PhpStorm to Xdebug on outside API calls

Tags: php, api, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm working on large website and API project. The code run inside a Docker and I managed to use the Xdebug perfectly when I use the normal web pages (in the browser localhost/ etc). However, when I access the API via Android app (connected to the localhost) the Xdebug doesn't work.

I configured PhpStorm with following keys:

localhost server:

- port: 80
- host: localhost

for the API server:

- port: 80
- host: my computer IP

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: are you sending xdebug headers from your android app call?

Comment: @delboy1978uk No, Why i need that?

Comment: You have to tell xdebug to initialise. from the browser, you'd either add that in the url, or set a session cookie header using a bookmarklet or browser addon like 'the easiest xdebug'

Comment: I didn't add anything in the browser and it works perfectly. In addition i set the remote_autostart = 1 in the docker, isn't that enough?

Comment: ah ok, you use that. I've had issues with that before. have you set allowed ips and so on?

Comment: IPs? no I just exposed the ports and I set .remote_host = my computer ip

Comment: is your android app running on an actual phone, or an emulator on your computer?

Comment: On actual phone, but from the app (test version) i set host to  my computer ip.
p.s: I checked the cookies  you are right there is XDEBUG_SESSION cookie in the browser!

Comment: right. So all you should need to do is set that same header from the phone app, and it should start working!

Comment: If it works, let me know, and I'll write a proper answer so other people can solve it too

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks! I'll try that and I'll tell you when it works

Comment: You don't have to specify `remote_host` you can use `remote_connect_back=1`.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Hi, I want you to know that I made an work around for the problem but it wasn't exactly what you suggested see my answer if you're interested. Anyway thank you since your answers gave me good directions and insights about my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone came here with similar problem: I solved the problem indirectly, while I wasn't able to detect the real source of the problem I made a workaround that was good enough for me. 
I installed Charles proxy (you can use any alternative if you want) then I connected my android mobile to Charles from WiFi settings (you should set the IP of the laptop running Charles and the port that is used by Charles like 8888), but since some of the API calls wasn't passing through the proxy I needed to install proxy app on my android so I chose Drony (The only working app *I'm aware of* that don't need your mobile to be rooted). Then for Xdebug all API calls from the mobile will seem as if they're coming from your laptop (through Charles). With this setup I was able to debug the web API normally. I Hope this helps someone!